# VSCode is commenting out code after /* in string literals. How can I disable this?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

VSCode is commenting out all the code behind from the part '/*' in the string literal on my JS file.

[image]
I don't want this behaviour.

Is there anybody who experienced some similar things like this using VSCode?

Whole code of this file is here

```
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';

async function getPost() {
    let posts = [];

    const paths = import.meta.glob('/src/posts/*.md', { eager: true });

    for (const path in paths) {
        console.log(path);
    }

    return posts;
}

export async function GET() {
    const post = await getPost();
    return json(post);
}
```

I tried to escape the asterisk in the string literal but the prettier auto fixed it.

```
'/src/posts/\*.md' => /src/posts/*.md' (auto fixed by prettier)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior using VS Code on macOS Version: 1.78.0 (Universal) with the snippet provided.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue either.  You might try doing a `Start Extension Bisect` command to see if one of your extensions is responsible.

Comment: are you using a babel extension? does the problem happen when you disable it? or if you change the language mode to plain js instead of babel js

Comment: @user I uninstalled babel and the problem is gone. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the plugins installed on VS Code and disabled Babel JS and JSDoc plugin.
It helped and it seems the problem is resolved.